# Multithreading in Scrapy using proxies

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to crawl about 4 million pages using scrapy. I am using [storm proxies](http://stormproxies.com/).
Lets say Number of threads allowed on my account is 20.
I want to ask -

Is multithreading means CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN , in scrapy.

or there is an any other way to do that.

How can I effectively use those 20 threads

NOTE - In case I am not clear with my question , please leave a comment, and I will try to elaborate according to that.

Comment: Hi sagar, Can you share your scrapy storm proxy middleware, please?
I am interested in doing something similar.

Comment: @sagar yes can you please share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight out of the docs:

> `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`- The maximum number of concurrent (ie.
>   simultaneous) requests that will be performed by the Scrapy
>   downloader.
>
> `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` - The maximum number of concurrent
>   (ie. simultaneous) requests that will be performed to any single
>   domain.
>
> `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP` - The maximum number of concurrent (ie.
>   simultaneous) requests that will be performed to any single IP. If
>   non-zero, the CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN setting is ignored, and
>   this one is used instead. In other words, concurrency limits will be
>   applied per IP, not per domain.

Answering your question directly

I suspect that that service only let's you scrape up to 20 threads overall, meaning it doesn't care what you are requesting so you should use `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` set to 20 maximum (default is 16).

Each request is "kind of a thread". It's built on top of [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Documentation). In the eyes of the proxy service you are using, there's no way to tell the difference so every request will be a proxy thread!

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell, how could I make 2 million request in a day, some best practices may be, I am currently able to make 40000 request using proxies

Comment: Do you have any way to monitor how many threads are open at any given point in time? In the proxy system

Comment: not really, I had used a middleware and set request.meta[proxy] = proxy(that they have provided me)

Comment: Please I am really stuck in increasing the efficiency of crawler, Is increasing CONCURRENT_REQUSTS is the only way to do that,, ?

Comment: You can use multiple servers and deploy the spider on them, feed the crawlers with the urls from a database so they don't overlap links (scrapy redis does this well), I see no other way besides increasing the infrastructure of the machine you're running the crawler in (like more cores, more ram, better network).